# How can I stop my computer from freezing every time I boot from suspend?

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my HP Probook 4540s laptop (2nd generation i5 model).If I suspend my computer and then use it after the suspend, everything freezes within 5 minutes of booting (from the suspend). I can't stop the freezing unless I force shutdown my laptop. I made sure I have all the software and driver updates. This problem has beeen happening since I installed Ubuntu on my machine 2 months ago.

Comment: Do you have a dual boot config with Windows?  If so, is fast startup disabled?

Comment: Also 2nd gen is quite old

Comment: @Nmath Yeah it is in a dual boot config with Windows, but Fast startup is disabled.
I will add the last syslog before the crash. 
Nov 25 22:15:36 user-HP-ProBook-4540s systemd[1155]: vte-spawn-adacba97-bb3a-4bf6-8360-27a4e2f1bfbd.scope: Succeeded.
Nov 25 22:15:36 user-HP-ProBook-4540s systemd[1155]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Succeeded. 
Nov 25 22:15:41 user-HP-ProBook-4540s systemd-resolved[942]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.

Comment: Nov 25 22:16:55 user-HP-ProBook-4540s systemd-resolved[942]: message repeated 59 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Nov 25 22:17:01 user-HP-ProBook-4540s CRON[25097]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 25 22:17:01 user-HP-ProBook-4540s systemd-resolved[942]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.

Comment: Nov 25 22:26:12 user-HP-ProBook-4540s systemd-resolved[942]: message repeated 380 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Nov 25 22:26:29 user-HP-ProBook-4540s systemd-resolved[942]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.

Comment: The freezing happened at 22:28, but the last log was at 22:26:12